# Extracting file names from an online data server in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to download numerous (1000s) of data files from a data server (e.g, http://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/thredds/catalog/GLDAS_NOAH10SUBP_3H/2011/345/). Unfortunately, the names of the files in each directory are not formatted in a similar way (the time that they were created were appended to the end of the file name). I need to be able to **specify the file name** to subset the data (I have a special tool for these data types) and download it. I cannot find a function in matlab that will extract the file names.

I have looked at URLREAD, but it downloads everything including html code.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily parse the link.

```
x=urlread(url)
links=regexp(x,'<a href=''([^>]+)''>','tokens')
```

Reads every link, you have to filter all unwanted links.

For example this gets all grb files:

```
a=regexp(x,'<a href=''([^>]+.grb)''>','tokens')
```